# What is the purpose of having such complicated C++ class design?

Tags: c++, design-patterns

I came across an open source C++ code and I got curious, why do people design the classes this way?

So first things first, here is the Abstract class:

```
class BaseMapServer
    {
    public:
        virtual ~BaseMapServer(){}

        virtual void LoadMapInfoFromFile(const std::string &file_name) = 0;
        virtual void LoadMapFromFile(const std::string &map_name) = 0;
        virtual void PublishMap() = 0;
        virtual void SetMap() = 0;
        virtual void ConnectROS() = 0;
    };
```

Nothing special here and having an abstract class can have several well understood reasons. So from this point, I thought maybe author wanted to share common features among other classes. So here is the next class, which is a seperate class but actually holds a pointer of type abstract class mentioned above (actual cpp file, other two classes are header files) :

```
class MapFactory
{
    BaseMapServer *CreateMap(
            const std::string &map_type,
            rclcpp::Node::SharedPtr node, const std::string &file_name)
        {
            if (map_type == "occupancy") return new OccGridServer(node, file_name);
            else
            {
                RCLCPP_ERROR(node->get_logger(), "map_factory.cpp 15: Cannot load map %s of type %s", file_name.c_str(), map_type.c_str());
                throw std::runtime_error("Map type not supported")
            }
        }
};
```

And now the interesting thing comes, here is the child class of the abstract class:

```
class OccGridServer : public BaseMapServer
    {
    public:
        explicit OccGridServer(rclcpp::Node::SharedPtr node) : node_(node) {}
        OccGridServer(rclcpp::Node::SharedPtr node, std::string file_name);
        OccGridServer(){}
        ~OccGridServer(){}

        virtual void LoadMapInfoFromFile(const std::string &file_name);
        virtual void LoadMapFromFile(const std::string &map_name);
        virtual void PublishMap();
        virtual void SetMap();
        virtual void ConnectROS();

    protected:
        enum MapMode { TRINARY, SCALE, RAW };

        // Info got from the YAML file
        double origin_[3];
        int negate_;
        double occ_th_;
        double free_th_;
        double res_;
        MapMode mode_ = TRINARY;
        std::string frame_id_ = "map";
        std::string map_name_;

        // In order to do ROS2 stuff like creating a service we need a node:
        rclcpp::Node::SharedPtr node_;

        // A service to provide the occupancy grid map and the message with response:
        rclcpp::Service<nav_msgs::srv::GetMap>::SharedPtr occ_service_;
        nav_msgs::msg::OccupancyGrid map_msg_;

        // Publish map periodically for the ROS1 via bridge:
        rclcpp::TimerBase::SharedPtr timer_;
    };
```

So what is the purpose of the `MapFactory` class?

To be more specific - what is the advantage of creating a class which holds a pointer of type Abstract class `BaseMapServer` which is a constructor (I believe) and this weird constructor creates a memory for the new object called `OccGridServer` and returns it? I got so confused by only writing this. I really want to become a better C++ coder and I am desperate to know the secret behind these code designs.

Comment: You're faced with a design pattern, called "factory".

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern

Comment: You're really asking about what problem the Factory pattern solves. It's simple if you know how to look at it: The code calling `MapFactory::CreateMap` needs to know `BaseMapServer` and the string `"occupancy"`, but it does *not* have to know `OccGridServer` to create one.

Comment: Inside `MapFactory`, `CreateMap` is a member function which returns a pointer to a `BaseFactory`. It is not a constructor.

Comment: It's a way of creating an object without knowing its exact type.

Comment: It is an interface declaration, completely hiding the implementation has many concrete advantages.  The factory is an implementation detail of the coding technique.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interface-based_programming

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `MapFactory` class is used to create the correct subclass instance of `BaseMapServer` based on the parameters passed to it.

In this particular case there is only one child class instance, but perhaps there are plans to add more.  Then when more are added the factory method can look something like this:

```
BaseMapServer *CreateMap(
        const std::string &map_type,
        rclcpp::Node::SharedPtr node, const std::string &file_name)
    {
        if (map_type == "occupancy") return new OccGridServer(node, file_name);
        // create Type2Server
        else if (map_type == "type2") return new Type2Server(node, file_name);   
        // create Type3Server
        else if (map_type == "type3") return new Type3Server(node, file_name);
        else
        {
            RCLCPP_ERROR(node->get_logger(), 
                         "map_factory.cpp 15: Cannot load map %s of type %s", 
                         file_name.c_str(), map_type.c_str());
            throw std::runtime_error("Map type not supported")
        }
    }
```

This has the advantage that the caller doesn't need to know the exact subclass  being used, and in fact the underlying subclass could potentially change or even be replaced under the hood without the calling code needing to be modified.  The factory method internalizes this logic for you.

Comment: Ok I see, that is super clever and your way of explaining with the example actually helped me to understand better than reading on Wikipedia.

Comment: Imagine the code is in a shared library used by thousands of applications and a bug is found in it. Imagine further that fixing the bug requires adding a new data member to `OccGridServer`. This pattern means those thousands of applications don't have to be recompiled and redeployed, only the library does.

Answer (score 0):

Its a Factory pattern. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern. It looks like the current code only supports one implementation (`OccGridServer`), but more could be added at a future date. Conversely, if there's only ever likely to be one concrete implementation, then it's overdesign.

Answer (score 0):

This is example of the factory design pattern. The use case is this: there are several types of very similar classes that will be used in code. In this case, `OccGridServer` is the only one actually shown, but a generic explanation might reference hypothetical `Dog`, `Cat`, `Otter`, etc. classes. Because of their similarity, some polymorphism is desired: if they all inherit from a base class `Animal` they can share virtual class methods like `::genus`, `::species`, etc., and the derived classes can be pointed to or referred to with base class pointers/references. In your case, `OccGridServer` inherits from `BaseMapServer`; presumably there are other derived classes as well, and pointers/references.

If you know which derived class is needed at compile time, you would normally just call its constructor. The point of the factory design pattern is to simplify selection of a derived class when the particular derived class is not known until runtime. Imagine that a user picks their favorite animal by selecting a button or typing in a name. This generally means that somewhere there's a big if/else block that maps from some type of I/O disambiguator (string, enum, etc.) to a particular derived class type, calling its constructor. It's useful to encapsulate this in a factory pattern, which can act like a named constructor that takes this disambiguator as a "constructor" parameter and finds the correct derived class to construct.

Typically, by the way, `CreateMap` would be a static method of `BaseMapServer`. I don't see why a separate class for the factory function is needed in this case.